# Как работает сокет в java

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, сокеты

Как работает сокет в java, как он подключает между собой клиент и сервер и позволяет им обмениваться данными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в 2х словах сокет - это канал связи между двумя приложениями в который оба пишут и читают сообщения.

Вот собрал Вам пример как соединить 2 приложения при помощи сокетов, запускайте сначала сервер, а потом уже клиент:

```
public class SocketExample extends JFrame {

    SocketExample(String name, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        JButton button = new JButton("send");
        setTitle(name);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        area.setEditable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bottomPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottomPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        button.addActionListener(a -> {
            area.setText(area.getText() + "you: " + field.getText() + '\n');
            out.println(field.getText());
            field.setText("");
        });

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        String inputLine;
                        if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                            area.setText(area.getText() + "remote: " + inputLine + '\n');
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("remote disconnected" );
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        addCloser(this, socket, out, in);
    }

    private static class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666);
            SocketExample server = new SocketExample("Server", serverSocket.accept());
            addCloser(server, serverSocket);
        }
    }

    private static class Client {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            new SocketExample("Client", new Socket("localhost", 6666));
        }
    }

    private static void addCloser(JFrame frame, Closeable... closeables){
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                for (Closeable closeable : closeables) {
                    try {
                        closeable.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Для краткости можно было и без GUI сделать)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, спасибо огромное за объяснение и пример!
Возникла одна небольшая проблемка, addCloser в обоих случаях выделяется красным и я никак не могу понять, что с этим делать, подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, java version "1.8.0_211"

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, при запуске сервера по поводу этого он ошибку не выводит (хотя красным и выделяет)
Но независимо от того, закомментировал я эту строку или нет он выдаёт такое вот:
Error:(23, 20) java: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(26, 20) java: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(30, 21) java: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(32, 21) java: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(36, 5) java: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, импорт java.io.Closeable; есть, но всё равно выделяет красным

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96350/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-semenov-nilolay).